# What are the advantages of WordPress over other systems?

Tags: cms, comparison

I've tried to explain the benefits of WordPress to others; comparing it to static sites is easy, as (most) everything can be done online with WP. I have more difficulty comparing and contrasting with other content management systems such as Drupal.

I realize that there is no perfect system for every use, but what features - if any - of WordPress would you point out as being easier or more useful, compared to other tools?

I am particularly interested in features regarding use of WP as a CMS, not just a blog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi **@Grant Palin**:

My use of WordPress is almost exclusively CMS, and the other software I have experience with is **Drupal** *(2 years ago, but have continued to follow it)* and **DotNetNuke** *(5 years ago, and I haven't looked back.)* I also reviewed **Joomla** about 3+ years ago and found is to be both too complex and too inflexible, so I never seriously considered it.

Anyway, I can only speak with any real authority about how WordPress compares with Drupal as a CMS, and as luck would have it I wrote a blog post about exactly topic last week:

- [**17 Reasons WordPress is a Better CMS than Drupal**](http://mikeschinkel.com/blog/17-reasons-wordpress-is-a-better-cms-than-drupal/)

Comment: Excellent blog post. That pointed out to me some aspects of Drupal that I did not know already. Good of you to mention some of Drupal's strengths vs WP as well. I think I'll focus on WP for now and tinker with D7 when it is released.

Comment: @Grant Palin - Thanks!  I do need to find time to answering some of the Drupal advocates because some of what they said needs addressing. :)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I *hate* to just add a plug for myself, but I use WordPress as a cms on my own site - http://dkuntz2.com.</strike>

**Update:** I no longer use WordPress.

While it's still mostly a blog, I do have a portfolio bit built in.

The main reasons I use WordPress over another cms are that I know WordPress, it has a huge community dedicated to supporting it, it's easy for someone who's never used it before to start and while it may technically be a hack, I've got my portfolio setup using post categories (I could set it up with custom taxonomies, but I use categories because I used it before taxonomies were out).

I'm not sure if other cms' have that ability, to keep things dynamic like a portfolio but still have a blog without using the same hack.

I use WordPress with clients because it's easier for them to use than Durpal. I would never use Joomla simply because it's really bloated and slow, and the admin area doesn't work very well. It's also nice that lots of people have written getting started guides for WordPress, so that I don't have to write a getting started guide myself, just a guide to how their site works.

Comment: Curious, why do you no longer use Wordpress and what do you use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Simply None...:(

You dont get flexibility with Wordpress and It is better to try Drupal if you want to build a website.

Though Wordpress Multi installation promises to make large websites it doesnt good enough for advanced users.

if your aim is to just write then go for Wordpress and If want your site to be like what you planned then go for Others...Drupal is best !!!